# Is it appropriate to use @PathParam to send authontication data

Tags: jax-rs, restful-authentication

I am wondering if it is appropriate to use @Pathparam to pass parameters to login method. I want to use the returned boolean value in a client but so far I haven't been able to get neither TRUE nor FALSE but bunch of XML tags.

```
@POST
@GET
@Path("{username}/{password}")
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public boolean login(@PathParam("usrName")String usrName, @PathParam("pwd")String pwd){
    List<User> users= super.findAll();

    for(User u : users){
        if(u.getUserName().equals(usrName) && u.getPassword().equals(pwd)){
            return true;
        }
    }        
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are thinking about security than `do not use PathParam or QueryParam` like annotations

use `@FormParam` to pass value to server
and use `POST request` for this

in you code i see GET & POST both methods 
do not use both for this type of operation

for authenticational data `Strictly use POST`.